# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException on hibernate version upgrade 4.3.1 to 5.4.x

Tags: java, hibernate

After upgrading hibernate version from 4.3.1 to 5.4.x, While performing `criteria.list();` it returns List type of result.

while I am trying to append some value in the same result list it shows me the error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
```

while the same append on result list is working on hibernate version 4.3.1.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The list that is being returned seems to be an unmodifyable list. Create your own new list (an `ArrayList` for instance) using to copy constructor to create a modifyable list.

Comment: Yes. but what is the change on hibernate upgrade? because the same code is running on the lower version.

Comment: you upgraded to a new major version. You should always expect to have breaking changes in major version upgrades.